# Double to Number

Tags: java, double, type-conversion, type-mismatch

How to convert Double to Number in Java, like in the code below?

```
public Number parse(String text, ParsePosition status) {
    // find the best number (defined as the one with the longest parse)
    int start = status.index;
    int furthest = start;
    double bestNumber = Double.NaN;
    double tempNumber = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < choiceFormats.length; ++i) {
        String tempString = choiceFormats[i];
        if (Misc.regionMatches(start, tempString, 0, tempString.length(), text)) {
            status.index = start + tempString.length();
            tempNumber = choiceLimits[i];
            if (status.index > furthest) {
                furthest = status.index;
                bestNumber = tempNumber;
                if (furthest == text.length()) break;
            }
        }
    }
    status.index = furthest;
    if (status.index == start) {
        status.errorIndex = furthest;
    }
    int c= 0;
    return new Double(bestNumber); 
}
```

But in Eclipse it shows

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Double to Number
```

Actually this code belongs to `ChoiceFormat.java` class from `java.text` package.

Comment: That suggests you've got a different `Double` type or a different `Number` type somewhere. You could try making it explicit with a declaration type of `java.lang.Number` and `return new java.lang.Double(bestNumber);`

Comment: I'm not getting any such error in eclipse

Comment: can you put the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[java.lang.Double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) is a subclass of [java.lang.Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). Hence the posted code shouldn't show any compilation error if you are returning a `java.lang.Double` from a method which returns `java.lang.Number` .

As Jon Skeet pointed out, *"you've got a different Double type or a different Number type somewhere"*. Please double check to see if you are using `java.lang.Double` and `java.lang.Number`.

Answer (score 2):

Use casting

```
Double d=new Double(2);
Number n=(Number)d;
```

in your case

```
Double d=new Double(bestNumber);
Number n=(Number)d;

return n;
```

Comment: There should be no need to do this though. Or rather - if this code were to work, the original code should have worked.

Comment: i tried it before it shows 'cannot cast form Double to Number'.

Comment: @Sanjaya Double is subclass of Number